# Issues with PDF formatting from a converted .DB file

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, pdf, reportlab

I have been trying to create this code that converts .db files from my computer into .pdf files. The code I made works, however the formatting is completely off on the pdf file. The left side of the pdf looks normal however it runs off onto the right and you cant even see what it says. Here is my current code:

```html
import sqlite3
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont

conn = sqlite3.connect(r'C:\Users\ethan\Cookies\Desktop\MattressFirm\BedTimes\bedtimes.db')

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('SELECT * FROM articles')

rows = cur.fetchall()

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('Arial', 'Arial.ttf'))

page_width, page_height = letter
left_margin = 25
right_margin = 25
top_margin = 25
bottom_margin = 25
column_width = (page_width - left_margin - right_margin) / len(rows[0])

pdf_file = canvas.Canvas('output.pdf', pagesize=letter)

y = page_height - top_margin
for row in rows:
    x = left_margin + ((page_width - left_margin - right_margin) - (column_width * len(row))) / 2
    for value in row:
        pdf_file.setFont('Arial', 10)
        pdf_file.drawString(x, y, str(value))
        x += column_width
    y -= 15
    if y < bottom_margin:
        pdf_file.showPage()
        y = page_height - top_margin

pdf_file.save()

conn.close()
```

Anyone got ideas on how to fix the format?

Edit: I thought it would also be helpful to mention that the specific .db file I am testing with only has 1 column.